# Unable to unzip using ZipArchieve in ios?

Tags: ios, unzip

I have downloaded a file(ZipSecretExcel.zip) which is stored in the document directory. I am now trying to unzip this file in the document directory using ZipArchieve using the following code:

```
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

     NSString *zipFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ZippSecretExcel.zip"];

     NSString *output = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UnZipSecret"];

     ZipArchive* za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];

     if( [za UnzipOpenFile:zipFilePath] ) {
     if( [za UnzipFileTo:output overWrite:YES] != NO ) {
     //unzip data success
     //do something
     //NSLog(@"Folder successfully zipped");
     }

     [za UnzipCloseFile];
     }
```

However, folder successfully zipped log message never gets printed which means there is failure in unzipping. Can anyone tell what is that I am doing wrong?